# get timestamp of noon PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I've got a timestamp, X.

Using PHP, how can I find the timestamp that represents noon of the day that X is from?

I guess I would need to convert X to a date, extract the day, and then convert noon from that day to a timestamp. Is there an easy way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`strtotime('noon', $timestamp)` should work

Comment: beautiful. i've tested and it indeed does the job! i will accept your answer in 9 minutes. strtotime seems like an awesome function

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$timestamp = 1346343553;
$date = getdate($timestamp);

$noon = mktime ( 12, 00, 00, $date['mon'], $date['day'], $date['year'] );

print $noon;
print date(DATE_RSS, $noon);
```

Of course, this goes without saying, but timezones are not factored at all. Also, `strtotime()` is probably the preferred method, but `getdate()` doesn't get enough love!

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime` supports many such strings, check documentation..[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
strtotime('noon', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a string:

```
echo date('Y-m-d 12:00:00', $time);
```

Comment: OP wants a timestamp though, not a string.

Comment: @Jack I understand what you mean. Does the OP? ... Does he mean "timestamp" as an `int`, a `string`, or a `DateTime`?

Comment: By the very mention of the word timestamp would you have signaled the intent; at least, that's my opinion :)

Comment: @Jack From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp): a sequence of characters... My opinion differs.